# jQuery Find elements with non empty data attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have few elements that contain data-attribute like so:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item" data-value="1"></div>
  <div class="item" data-value="2"></div>
  <div class="item" data-value=""></div>
</div>
```

Them I try to use something like:

```
$("#container").find("[data-value]:not(empty)").css({"padding":10});
```

Basically I want to set padding on all items that have data-values set, if data-values is empty, leave it alone.

Comment: what is the error you are facing? does it throw errors in the console? does it not work at all? or does it work select the wrong elements? or is the css not shown right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.filter()`

This might get you started

```js
$('button').click(function(){
   $('div.item').filter(function(i){
      return $(this).attr('data-value') != "";
   }).css('background','yellow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="item" data-value="1">One</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="2">Two</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="">Three</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="3">Four</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="">Five</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="4">Six</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="">Seven</div>
</div>
<button>Find MT Data</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```js
$("#container").children().filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('value')
}).css({
  "padding": "10px"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item" data-value="1">1</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="2">2</div>
  <div class="item" data-value="">3</div>
</div>
```